# How to provision odata service by using s4sdk?

Tags: s4sdk

I have create a project by using s4sdk and build a spring boot application which can consume the ODATA service provided by a on-premise ABAP backend system (by leveraging VDM). Now I want to make my application able to provision some ODATA service to outside. I know "SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development" can do it. Do I need to introduce it into my project and how? Or "s4sdk" already contains it. I notice I can already use the annotation like "@Read" to create service implementation class in my project. But after creating the implementation class and put the edmx file under the resource/edmx fold. The exposed ODATA service doesn't work. Any tips for that? Thanks very much.

Comment: Hello eric, if Emdee's answer satisfied you, please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me refer you to the blog series about the [SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/01/sap-cloud-platform-sdk-for-service-development-overview-of-blogs/).

The reason why you can use `@Read` is, as you have already assumed, that the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK already declares the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development in its BOM.

Apart from that, while the SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK manages the correct version of the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development, we recommend that you mention the dependency of the SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development explicitly in your pom.xml (w/o hard-wiring its version).

Comment: Hi Emdee, thanks very much for the reply. Based on your statement, my understanding is that I can use the features provided by "SAP Cloud Platform SDK for service development" out of box if I create my project archetype by using SAP S/4HANA Cloud SDK. Am I correct? I was aware of the blog series you shared. I followed the steps from the blog series to provision my ODATA service but didn't make it. I suppose I miss some configuration steps but have no idea what they are.

Comment: Yes, your statement is correct. If your own provisioning does not work, kindly open another question to address the concrete issue by mentioning the error message and showing the code.